# Android-Controlled Car [General Info]

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, microcontroller, remote-control

This is a very beginner's question. I'm trying to control a car over Bluetooth on an Android Device. Although I'm no expert but once I know a little, I can start working on it.

The functionality of the car that I want to control via Android Device is:

- fire up the engine (ignition)
- steer the car's wheel
- accelerate the gas pedal
- brake
- shift gears

I know I would need mechanical micro-controllers for this but don't have any experience in this field. My QUESTION is where to start and what would I need to do? And any software that might help me with it.

Answer (score 0):

For this you have to start with Micro-controller implementation. make a circuit which can get data from bluetooth device and according to it, micro-controller will trigger relays which will do your above work. while in android APP you can make APP which will send particular data (Like 1,2,3,4 for each work).